# Java String byte array com números negativos

Tags: java, string, utf-8, iso-8859-1, codificação-de-conteúdo

Estou enfrentando problemas em descobrir a codificação de uma string.

A entrada é:

```
São Paulo
```

A leitura original desse conteúdo não me compete, pois o texto passa por um wrapper de Lua para Java.

Do meu lado, já fiz a seguinte tentativa "força bruta" e não acho a conversão correta:

```
byte[] bytes1 = entrada.getBytes();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes1));
System.out.println(new String(bytes1));
System.out.println(new String(bytes1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println(new String(bytes1, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
System.out.println(new String(bytes1, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

byte[] bytes2 = entrada.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes2));
System.out.println(new String(bytes2));
System.out.println(new String(bytes2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println(new String(bytes2, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
System.out.println(new String(bytes2, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

byte[] bytes3 = entrada.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes3));
System.out.println(new String(bytes3));
System.out.println(new String(bytes3, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println(new String(bytes3, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
System.out.println(new String(bytes3, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

byte[] bytes4 = entrada.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes4));
System.out.println(new String(bytes4));
System.out.println(new String(bytes4, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println(new String(bytes4, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
System.out.println(new String(bytes4, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
```

E tenho a seguinte saída, toda errada:

```
[83, -29, -81, -96, 80, 97, 117, 108, 111]
S㯠Paulo
S㯠Paulo
Sã¯ Paulo
S���Paulo

[83, -29, -81, -96, 80, 97, 117, 108, 111]
S㯠Paulo
S㯠Paulo
Sã¯ Paulo
S���Paulo

[83, 63, 80, 97, 117, 108, 111]
S?Paulo
S?Paulo
S?Paulo
S?Paulo

[83, 63, 80, 97, 117, 108, 111]
S?Paulo
S?Paulo
S?Paulo
S?Paulo
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 3):

Se `entrada` for uma `String`, você já tem ela decodificada e não adianta tentar convertê-la.

Me parece que o que você está tentando fazer é converter a `String` em bytes e depois os bytes numa `String` novamente. Isso não funciona pois uma vez que o *input* original foi transformado numa `String`, em geral os bytes são decodificados e não permanecem os mesmos que eram originalmente.

Quando você faz `entrada.getBytes()` na verdade o Java vai usar o *encoding* padrão definido pelo seu sistema, então não tem diferença alguma das outras abordagens.

Os números negativos são normais, já que o tipo primitivo `byte` em Java é um número que vai de `-128` a `+127`. Nada mais normal que alguns caracteres sendo representados por valores dentro do intervalo negativo.

O seguinte código faz a decodificação do vetor de bytes em todas as codificações que o Java suporta num determinado ambiente:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { 83, -29, -81, -96, 80, 97, 117, 108, 111 };
SortedMap<String, Charset> charsets = Charset.availableCharsets();
for (Map.Entry<String, Charset> entry : charsets.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", entry.getKey(), new String(b, entry.getValue()));
}
```

Testei isso num Mac e nenhuma codificação foi capaz de decodificar o `o` do `são`, o que me indica que os bytes já estão corrompidos e o problema não está em algum ponto anterior.

Você deve exigir de quem estiver do "outro lado" uma especificação de qual a codificação usada e que a implementação siga o que foi definido.

Outra abordagem seria receber diretamente o array de bytes da entrada ou algum formato que não faça uma decodificação dos bytes antes de chegar ao seu controle.

Comment: De fato, pois o `o` do Paulo deveria ser o mesmo código do `o` do São. Os dados estão corrompidos na entrada. A melhor coisa que o autor faria, seria mostrar a entrada byte a byte em hexa, para análise.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção. Concordo com vocês, e suspeitava disso também. Verei o que posso fazer sobre a leitura no Lua.